# What is GIMP's algorithm for generating an optimum palette for indexed images?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, png, gimp, color-palette

GIMP can convert images from RGB mode to Indexed mode through the "Convert Image to Indexed Colors" dialog (Image > Mode > Indexed...). In that dialog, there is an option to generate an optimum palette with a specified maximum number of colors in the generated palette. For images that contain huge regions of the same color (e.g. screenshots of windows), generating an optimum palette could substantially reduce the file size of exported images while having minimal quality loss.

[image: Convert Image to Indexed Colors dialog in GIMP]

For screenshots in PNG format, I noticed that GIMP almost always produces smaller images with its optimum palette algorithm than when I use ImageMagick 6 to reduce colors via its [`-colors`](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colors) option. While ImageMagick's documentation describes the [color reduction algorithm](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/quantize.php) that ImageMagick uses, GIMP's documentation does not describe GIMP's  algorithm.

What is GIMP's algorithm for generating an optimum palette?

(GNU Image Manipulation Program version 2.10.34)

Comment: either you'll get an answer from someone who *knows*, or you'll be told to look in GIMP's source code. in other words: it's a question you can answer by yourself with a little research.

Comment: I don't use GIMP and don't know the answer, but you could consider comparing its output with `pngquant` which uses `libimagequant` under the hood for a quick test. I am not endorsing `pngquant` either and would recommend running it in a *"safe"* environment if you feel inclined to try it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The relevant code is in [app/core/gimpimage-convert-indexed.c](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/blob/b073805fb3cc3563aa0278573fb74364862ca21b/app/core/gimpimage-convert-indexed.c). I had attempted to understand it prior to asking this question, but my C is not that good. It seems that GIMP adds black (#000000) and/or white (#FFFFFF) to the color palette if the input image contains black and/or white pixels. ImageMagick does not do that. Other than that, I have not been able to understand much of the code.

Comment: I don't fault you. 4.5 kloc in a single file is a lot to digest. it mentions "boxes" a lot. I haven't investigated that. I found mention of "[median cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_cut)". that is one of many clustering methods. it seems to be a simple and fast method. it doesn't require iteration (optimization) like k-means would. I can't predict how median cut will behave, i.e. how it compares in terms of quality vs. k-means.